# Spring data Oracle JPA performance with pagination

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa, large-data

I am looking to retrieve a large dataset with a `JpaRepository`, backed by Oracle
table. The choices are to return a collection (`List`) or a `Page` of the entity and then step through the results. Please note - *I have to consume every record in this set, exactly once.* This is not a "look-for-the-first-one-from-a-large-dataset-and-return" operation.

While the paging idea is appealing, the performance will be horrible (n^2) because for each page queried, oracle will have to pull up previous n-1 pages, making the performance progressively worse as I get deeper in the result set.

My understanding of the `List` alternative is that the entire result-set will be loaded in memory. For oracle JPA spring does not have a backing result-set.

So here are my questions

1. Is my understanding of the  way `List` works with Spring Data correct? If it's not then I will just use `List`.
2. If I am correct, is there an alternative that *streams* Oracle/JPA result-sets?
3. Is there a third way that I am not aware of.

Comment: Don't use an obfuscation layer (aka "ORM"). Use plain JDBC and iterate over the `ResultSet` - then there is no need to keep anything else then the current row in memory.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks. I can use JDBC with forward-only result-set, but I would prefer an alternative that uses Spring Data since that is what the rest of the project uses.

Comment: If you want performance and (memory) efficiency then there is no alternative to a "direct" JDBC call.

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name, and you can pass through JPA using named queries https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Answer (score 1):

Pageable methods in SDJ call additional `select count(*) from ...` every request. I think this is reason of the problem. 
To avoid it you can use `Slice` instead of `Page` as return parameter, for example:

```
Slice<User> getAllBy(Pageable pageable);
```

Or you can use even `List` of entities with pagination:

```
List<User> getAllBy(Pageable pageable);
```

Additional [info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters)